# Building Api from mysql database users table, but when testing I get 404 status. Any Advise

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, http-status-code-404

I tried to test the API, but I get a 404 status. Any advice?
After testing:
{
"timestamp": "2022-03-29T01:50:58.126+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"path": "/api/v1/users"
}
I'm not sure if the problem is in the database itself or something went wrong with my code for the controller?

**User Table:**

```
package com.infosys.models;
import com.infosys.role_type.RoleType;
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email" )
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private RoleType role;


}
```

Role Table

```
package com.infosys.models;
import com.infosys.role_type.RoleType;
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="role")
@Data
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private RoleType role_type;

}
```

Employee Table:

```
package com.infosys.models;
import com.infosys.role_type.RoleType;
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private RoleType role;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_has_manager",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    )
    private Set<Manager> manager = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User users;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalTime startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private LocalTime endTime;

    @Column(name = "total_hrs")
    private Long totalHrs;
}
```

Manager Table:

```
package com.infosys.models;
import com.infosys.role_type.RoleType;
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="manager")
@Data
public class Manager {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User users;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private RoleType role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private Set<Employee> employee = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "employee_review")
    private String employeeReview;

}
```

User Repository:

```
package com.infosys.repositories;
import com.infosys.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

User Controller:

```
package com.infosys.controllers;
import com.infosys.models.User;
import com.infosys.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    // get all users
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String getAllUsers() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Spring App:

```
package com.infosys;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan("com.infosys.repositories")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

Comment: Just ensure if you defined context path in application.properties file?

Comment: Did you notice any error on your console during compile time? Is there any log printed when you go to "/api/v1/users"? If any error does not exist, first thing you need to think about is context path which @Ahmed Moussa mentioned above.